how to switch audio autput devices using NW.js
I would like to have a controll over the audio output devices on my NW.js application.
But it seems that NW.js does not support this.
I know how to change the audio output of single  or  elements in my application but i need to change it for the complete page since it has several sub pages that can change.
So the question is:
Is it possible to change the default audio output device in NW.js?
(the subpages always use the default.)
Is it possible to sort out some of the audio devices so the subpages are forced to use the remaining devices?
Plan B would be to controll it via windows settings by PowerShell.
